# How can I install Windows 8 as a dual boot over an existing Ubuntu installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I found many tutorials on how to do the opposite: Add Ubuntu onto an existing Windows Install. I can't find any that will let me install Windows 8 as a dual boot over Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to install Windows 8.1 next to Ubuntu 13.04, I assume your configuration would work the same way:

1. Create a partition for Windows
2. Boot the installer
3. Choose the partition previously dedicated to Windows
4. Follow the Windows installer
5. After installing Windows, [repair the GRUB bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/109543). Whatever method you use, make sure you used the same Ubuntu disk as you originally used, both in version and in architecture!